# as3 sound stream stop

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, stream

i am creating an online radio but i am having a weird problem, the code works for 5 times! after that the play button won't function!

I am not sure if this is relevant but i am also getting *SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context.* when i close the swf player.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
var streaming:Boolean;
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, music_on)

function music_on(event:MouseEvent):void
{   

var sndChannel:SoundChannel=new SoundChannel();
var s:Sound = new Sound();



    if (!streaming)
    {   gotoAndStop(2);             
        var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://127.0.0.1:8000/listen.mp3");
        var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(2000,false);
        s.load(req, context);
        sndChannel=s.play();
        streaming=true;         
    }
    else
    {
        gotoAndStop(1);

        streaming=false;
        sndChannel.stop();
        SoundMixer.stopAll();
        trace ("not playing");
    }
}
stop();
```

Comment: Does won't function means that mouse clicks are not being handled or it is not playing the sound. If it is not playing the sound, then it must be tracing "not playing" text. Right?

Comment: You are perfectly right, the button is working because i am getting "playing" or "not playing" it has to do something with the variable holding the sound right?

Comment: Have you tried not recreating the URLRequest/SoundLoaderContext every time you press play? Maybe try to store them as local members and call s.play() only.

Comment: Thank you for your time!!Seems i had to close the s (Sound variable).For some reason adding s.close(); after the sndChannel.stop(); fixed the problem!